# How to find type of singularity and residue of $f(x)=\sin\left(e^{1/x}\right)$?

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus, singularity

How to find type of singularity and residue of $f(x)=\sin\left(e^{1/x}\right)$.

Singularity is $x_0=0$, but how do I find limit of this function to determine type of singularity?

Answer (score 1):

Notice that as $x\to0^+$ we have $e^{1/x}\to+\infty$ so that in particular $f$ oscillates wildly in $[-1,1]$ as $x\to0^+$. Therefore, the singularity is not removable.

Moreover, because the real sine is bounded, the singularity cannot be a pole $(|f|$ remains bounded near $x_0=0$ for real values of $x)$. It follows that the only possibility is that $x_0$ is an essential singularity.

---

EDIT: Generally, one uses *residue* when referring to meromorphic functions, that is, functions which are holomorphic except at some isolated points, which are poles. However, we may define residue more generally as follows:

For any pair of radii $0\leq r<R$, any holomorphic function $f$ defined on the annulus

$$A(r,R,z_0)=\{z\in\mathbb{C}\,|\,r<|z-z_0|<R\}$$

has a unique Laurent series expansion. This means there are unique coefficients ${(a_k)}_{k\in\mathbb{Z}}$ with

$$f(z)=\sum_{k=-\infty}^{+\infty}a_k\,{(z-z_0)}^k\tag{$*$}$$

for all $z \in A(r,R,z_0)$. The *residue* of $f$ at $z_0$ is the coefficient $a_{-1}$ when $r=0$ (notice that it does not depend on the value of $R$).

By uniqueness of the Laurent series expansion, however you find the coefficients of a series of the form $(*)$, the resulting series will be the Laurent expansion (provided, of course, it converges to $f$).

Can you think of any ways to find the Laurent series expansion for $f$ around $x_0=0$?

Comment: Can you give me some directions how to find residue?

Comment: @Majica See the edit.

Answer (score 1):

The question about identifying the singularity has been answered well in the other answer, so I will answer about calculating the residue:
$$f(z)=\sin(e^{1/z})=e^{1/z}-\frac{e^{3/x}}{3!}+\frac{e^{5/x}}{5!}-...\\=(1+\frac1z+\frac1{2!z^2}+...)-\frac{1}{3!}(1+\frac3z+\frac3{2!z^2}+...)+\frac{1}{5!}(1+\frac5z+\frac5{2!z^2}+...)-...$$
So the residue, which is the coefficient of $z^{-1}$ is $$\frac1{0!}-\frac1{2!}+\frac1{4!}-\frac1{6!}+...=\cos(1)\approx0.54$$

Comment: Sorry, but I understand how did you get residue?

Comment: There are different definitions of the residue but they lead to the residue being the coefficient of $z^{-1}$ when you write out $f(z)$ as a Laurent Series. This is what I have done, but expanding $\sin$ as a Taylor series, and then the $\exp$ as a Taylor series. Then collect all the terms with $\frac1z$, and add the coefficients.